# Stylus not compiling everything in one .styl file

Tags: css, stylus

It's weird. Stylus was perfectly working, until I copy paste some css to try something.

When I added this to my style.styl file :

```
.navigation
  list-style none
  background white
  width 100%
  height 100%
  position fixed
  top 0
  right 0
  bottom 0
  left 0
  z-index 0
```

it compiled to this

```
.navigation,
list-style none,
background white,
width 100%,
height 100%,
position fixed,
top 0,
right 0,
bottom 0,
left 0,
z-index 0,
```

the rest of the css is compiling fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're using space-based indentation in your stylus-sheet.

Stylus default is tab indented. But you can use 4 or 2 spaces if you write it between curly brackets.

```
 .navigation {
    list-style none
    background white
    width 100%
    height 100%
    position fixed
    top 0
    right 0
    bottom 0
    left 0
    z-index 0
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have a wrong indentation inside your file where you pasted this code. Could you show an original file?